# Import custom .py files in Jupyter Notebook for Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Where do I store custom .py files for Anaconda3 on Mac, so that I can import them as packages in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can store them anywhere if you insert

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("path/to/module.py"))

from module import *
```