# How to proper import py files in jupyter and get access to modules that are also imported inside this py file?

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm not new to python, but somehow i never used that mechanic:
For example:
I have a python file **test.py** which looks like:

```
'''test.py'''
from anothertest import anothertestfunc
def test(a):
   return a
```

if i import that file in a jupyter notebook like:

```
[1] import test
```

how can i load that anothertestfunc-module in jupyter, so i can use it like

```
[1] import test
[2] anothertestfunc
```

for now i only get the errormessage "anotherfunc is not defined" that totally makes sense to me. But how is the proper way to import a py file,that also has modules imported inside, so i  use that modules once loaded in jupyter?

thanks in advance

Comment: you can find answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264194/import-py-file-in-another-directory-in-jupyter-notebook or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293427/import-custom-py-files-in-jupyter-notebook-for-anaconda3

Comment: `test.anothertestfunc`?